# Changing \mode in beamer makes a new paragraph. Is it possible to avoid it?

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I want to write different text in the middle of a sentence in a `beamer` presentation and its corresponding `beamerarticle`. But it seems that `\mode<...>{...}` introduces a new paragraph and breaks the sentence.

Please look at the code and results:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is a frame}

This is some text in \texttt{beamer} and \texttt{article} modes. 

This is some text in \mode<article>{\texttt{article}}\mode<beamer>{\texttt{beamer}} mode.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the result in `beamer` mode. It looks like `\mode<beamer>{text}` introduces `\par` (or something similar) before and after `text`. 
[image]

while `\mode<article>{text}` just introduces `\par` after `text`. 
[image]

In any case I would like t have some mechanism to alternate text without introducing paragraph breaks. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to achieve the same end: replace your `\mode` with `\only`.  I tend to think of `\mode` as something for Big Chunks and don't think I've ever used it *within* a frame.  That's purely subjective, but based on the question it would appear that inadvertently stumbled on a Good Practice.

Overlay specifications as used by `\only`, `\alt`, and `\temporal` (amongst others) can include "output type" specifications.  Quite often I'll do some complicated overlay stuff, for example I might want to iterate through approximations of `\pi`.  In my presentation, I'd want something like:

```
\only<+>{3}
\only<+>{3.2}
\only<+>{3.14}
```

But in `handout` or `trans` mode, these all get processed and the overlay specification collapses so that they all appear.  That isn't what I want.  So I actually do:

```
\only<+|handout: 0|trans: 0>{3}
```

and so on.  This suppresses the text completely in `handout` and `trans` modes.

In your example, you can make use of this facility and have:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is a frame}

This is some text in \texttt{beamer} and \texttt{article} modes. 

This is some text in
\only<article>{\texttt{article}}\only<beamer>{\texttt{beamer}} mode.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Output of example using only instead of mode]

Answer (score 7):

You can redefine `\beamer@modeinline` defined in `beamerbasemodes.sty`; here's the original definition:

```
\long\def\beamer@modeinline<#1>#2{%
  \gdef\beamer@closer{}%
  \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{\@gobble}\def\beamer@doifinframe{\@firstofone}%
  {\beamer@saveanother\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
   \beamer@masterdecode{#1}%
   \beamer@restoreanother}\beamer@donow{#2}%
  \beamer@mode\par}
```

and the final `\par` produces the end of paragraph you mentioned; deleting this `\par` command gives you what you want:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@modeinline<#1>#2{%
  \gdef\beamer@closer{}%
  \def\beamer@doifnotinframe{\@gobble}\def\beamer@doifinframe{\@firstofone}%
  {\beamer@saveanother\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
   \beamer@masterdecode{#1}%
   \beamer@restoreanother}\beamer@donow{#2}%
  \beamer@mode}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is a frame}

This is some text in \texttt{beamer} and \texttt{article} modes. 

This is some text in \mode<article>{\texttt{article}}\mode<beamer>{\texttt{beamer}} mode.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `etoolbox` package simplifies the code:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@modeinline}{\par}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{This is a frame}

This is some text in \texttt{beamer} and \texttt{article} modes. 

This is some text in \mode<article>{\texttt{article}}\mode<beamer>{\texttt{beamer}} mode.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I'll test as soon as possible. I still have a curiosity, with your example both `\par`, before and after `beamer` disappear but your solition just supresses one `\par` from `\beamer@modeinline`, so, where does the other one come from?

Comment: @Ignasi: every use of the original `\mode<...>{...}` command will result in introducing one `\par` command after the contents has been typeset. Schematically, what happens with the second line of text in your example is the following: in `beamer` mode the text becomes `This is some text in \par \texttt{beamer} \par mode.` (producing three paragraphs of text), but in `article` mode you will have `This is some text in \texttt{article} \par\par mode.` and two consecutive `\par` commands are equivalent to just one \par command, so you'll get only two paragraphs.

Comment: @Ignasi the redefinition suppresses `\par` from every occurrence of `\mode<...>{...}` so, in both cases of your example, after the redefinition, the two `\par` commands are suppressed producing just one paragraph in the output.